# LiveData from ViewModel overrides savedInstanceState on Fragment after rotation

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a Fragment with form to edit some data. It uses ViewModel with LiveData to load data from repository and update its status (eg. whether it was saved correctly). Loaded data is populated into EditText.

LiveData is set up as below

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        viewModel.loadDataFromRepo(dataId)
    }

    viewModel.data.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer<Data> { data ->
            editText.setText(data)
        }
    )
}
```

When user enters the screen, data is populated correctly and saving works as intended. However, if user edits the data, and rotates the screen without saving, `editText` is populated with original data value persisted in repository instead of edited data that is saved in `savedInstanceState`.

This is of course caused by LiveData observer being triggered after state was restored from `savedInstanceState`. However, with similiar setup in Activity (same code called in `onCreate`), it works as intended.

How to modify the code in order to `savedInstanceState` be used?

Comment: Why do you have two different values of one variable/instance in two places? Can't you just update the viewmodel value instead of keeping a separate copy in fragment?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir ViewModel holds value that is saved in the repository (eg. in external database accessed using REST), Fragment holds volatile value only for UI.

I suppose, i can keep data in a "draft state" in ViewModel, but it seems a little redundant when savedInstanceState mechanism exists.